# php link to system filename with strange characters

Tags: php, special-characters, filenames, urlencode

I'm trying to display an image which has strange characters in the OS filesys. I think the OS is CentOS Linux. I'm not sure what character encoding the OS filenames has, or if an 'ö' is always encoded the same way in the filename. At least the files that contain 'ö' in this folder do converted in the src to %F6 in the code below, but the browser cannot find the file. I have found no way to browse to these ö-files on the server.

```
$content = '';
$images = scandir("gallery/test");
foreach( $images as $im )
{
        $im_rurl = rawurlencode($im);
        if ( is_dir("gallery/$im") ) continue;
        $content .= "<img src='gallery/test/$im_rurl' />";
}
echo $content;
```

Can you please help me to access these files from the browser?

Comment: Have you tried without the encoding?

Comment: welcome to the fun world of filename encodings. Linux does not have a notion of encoding in the filesystem, so what you specify when creating the file will be kept -> it won't be consistent. And the browser will potentially use a different encoding again.

Comment: the purpose of this solution is to automatically generate an image gallery from an ftp upload...would you say php+linux is unable to do that? at least apache should be able to list the files, how would it work in such a case?

PeeHaa, yes, it did not work.